# Tkinter can't insert into Text Widgets with pack_forget()

Tags: python, tkinter

My application can receive multiple jobs which it processes using threads. I've created Tabs which contain a Text Widget for each job, but I'm having trouble inserting text into the text widgets.

No error the application just hangs.

Tabs are generated using the script found here: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577261-python-tkinter-tabs/

The tabs are a subclass of Frames that use pack_forget() to hide when they're not selected.

A simplified version of my App

server.py

```
class supply_thread(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, _sock, app):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.app = app


    def run(self):

        def close_tab():
            print 'Terminating supply.'
            new_supply.kill()


        # Create new tab
        self.tab = Frame(self.app)
        self.tab.pack()
        #self.tab.pack_forget() # <-- inserting this causes the app to hang

        # Scrollbar
        self.scrollbar = Scrollbar(self.tab)
        self.scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

        # Text
        self.text = Text(self.tab, yscrollcommand=self.scrollbar.set)
        self.scrollbar.config(command=self.text.yview)

        self.text.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)

        # Close
        self.button = Button(self.tab, text="CLOSE", command=close_tab)
        self.button.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=BOTH, expand=YES)



        print 'Starting thread' , data[0]['job'] , data[0]['supply']['dir_name'] , self.getName()
        logging.info(data[0])
        new_supply = supply.supply(data, self.app, self.text)
        new_supply.run()
        print 'Closing Thread' , data[0]['job'] , data[0]['supply']['dir_name'] , self.getName()
```

main.py

```
class App(Tk):

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Tk.__init__(self, master)

        tab1 = Frame(self)
        tab1.pack()

        self.scrollbar = Scrollbar(tab1)
        self.scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

        self.text1 = Text(tab1, yscrollcommand=self.scrollbar.set)
        self.scrollbar.config(command=self.text1.yview)
        self.text1.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()

    server = server(app)
    server.daemon = True
    server.start()

    app.mainloop()
```

I think this is what is causing the issue... If so is there an alternative?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pack_forget` has no effect on whether you can insert into a text widget or not. There is not enough information in your question to give you an answer.

If you're using threads, is it possible that you are trying to insert text from within a thread? You can only call widget methods from the main thread. Though, typically the result of this is that the program crashes rather than hangs.

When a tkinter app hangs, that is sometimes a symptom of trying to use both `pack` and `grid` in the same container widget. Are you doing that?

Comment: I've added sample code to my question. If I run the program without pack_forget() then it runs as normal and text is output to the respective text widgets. But if I add the pack_forget() command as shown in the code above it hangs.
I've used pack consistently throughout my code.

Comment: The problem is that you're calling Tkinter commands from the worker thread. You can't do that. You need to re-architect your code so that you only call tkinter commands from the main thread.

Comment: Threading issues can be hard to understand. The bigger question is why did the code work in the first place. Luck is as good a reason as any. Tkinter is simply not thread safe.

Comment: Seems you were right, I've restructured my code to have the tabs created in the main thread and they seem to be working fine now.